# How to convert a Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Runtime XAML app

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8

How do i convert my Windows Phone 8 app(already developed app) to a Windows Runtime XAML app. This is required because i needed to perform automation testing using Microsoft tool(Coded UI Testing) whice requires the app to be Windows Runtime XAML app.Is there any tool to convert or the VS 2013 would help.??
I have refered some msdn links 
[Migrating your Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Runtime XAML app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642486(v=vs.105).aspx) and also [Porting a Windows Phone Silverlight app to a XAML WinRT app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136.aspx)
but nothing was of much help.

Answer (score 0):

There are no automated tools for this. You'll need to manually convert it. How difficult this will be depends greatly on the application, how well separated its UI and data logic are, and which parts of the .Net Framework it uses. The documentation you linked provides alternatives for some classes. You will also need to upgrade the Xaml code to match Windows.UI.Xaml's usage.

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 (or later) will be necessary to create a Windows Phone Runtime app, but it doesn't provide any conversion tools.